# Scheduled Flow Not Running for All Records

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, bulkification, invocable-method

I am hoping someone can help me with Schedule-Triggered Flows (STF).

I have created a STF that gets all leads matching a specific criteria. The flow then checks the record type of the lead.

```
If (Record Type = A)
   Run Invocable Apex Code
ELSE 
   Do nothing
```

The apex code runs perfectly when executed through the lead trigger, but when executing through the STF it does not seem to be picking up all of the leads. I have tested this by scheduling the flow and checking the results against a SOQL query to see how many are unprocessed.

How can I ensure that the flow is running for every lead that matches the criteria? Any other insight would also be massively appreciated.

In the meantime I have written a schedulable apex class (which I was trying to avoid by using the flow) as a last resort.

Comment: What is lead sharing like. Wondering if the autoproc user can't see those leads? I had issues w autoproc user getting access to an apex class. Can you add some debugging to the flow to count the number of matching records and try to suss out which ones are missing?  Have not had this issue myself.

Comment: what's your invocable apex code look like? If you add a debug log to the automated process user and then schedule the flow to run, do you get any more information?

Comment: I get tons of information back, which is partly the problem. 
The invocable code runs perfectly, it just doesn't seem to pick up all of the leads.

I have bypassed this by writing a schedulable apex class for this.

Comment: what's your query like (ex. filters) in the scheduled flow?